# How to calculate main effects of factors in R with DOE.base and/or FrF2 packages?

Tags: r

New to DoE. For the following $2^3$ factorial design coded with `DoE.base` package in R:

```
### Create a 2^3 factorial design
plasma.2kdesign <- 
  fac.design(nfactors = 3, replications = 2, randomize = FALSE, 
             factor.names = list(A = c(-1, 1), B = c(-1, 1), C = c(-1, 1)))

etch <- c(550, 669, 633, 642, 1037, 749, 1075, 729, 
          604, 650, 601, 635, 1052, 868, 1063, 860)

plasma.2kdesign <- add.response(design = plasma.2kdesign, response = etch)
```

ANOVA, regression, and main effects & interactions plots are possible by the following code with `DoE.base` and `FrF2` packages:

```
### ANOVA
plasma.aov <- aov(etch ~ A * B * C, data = plasma.2kdesign)
summary(plasma.aov)

### Plot main effects and interactions
MEPlot(plasma.2kdesign)
IAPlot(plasma.2kdesign)

### Regression
plasma.lm <- lm(etch ~ A * B * C, data = plasma.2kdesign)
summary(plasma.lm)
```

**How do I calculate the main effects of $A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC$ with functions in `DoE.base` and/or `FrF2` packages?** Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just figured it out. The regression coefficients are **one-half** the corresponding factor effect estimates because a regression coefficient measures the effect of a one-unit change in $x$ on the mean of $y$, and the effect estimate is based on a two-unit change (from -1 to +1).